# Best way to develop with Spring Boot + IntelliJ

Tags: spring, tomcat, intellij-idea, spring-boot

We've got a product that is built on top of Spring Boot and deployed via an executable war via embedded Tomcat, but during development we've adopted the approach of developing on a hosted Tomcat so our IDEs (IntelliJ mostly) will have hot-swap / redeploy support (rather than cycling our entire app, which takes a while to boot).

We recently added `spring-boot-starter-websocket` to our project & have run into issues with the hosted Tomcat's classloader using the embedded Tomcat's resources and crapping out. We can get around it by using profiles and marking the embedded libs as `provided` so that only our CI builds include them, but it's error prone & hacky at best.

---

So, my question is this: **is there a better way of doing things?** Using the Maven plugin or the runnable class introduces problems, as the maven plugin won't hotswap and the runnable class has issues finding classpath things like JSPs (wish we had switched to Thymeleaf beforehand, but next time ;)

The requirements for a "better" development cycle would be:

1. Code hotswap - aka not having to restart the app / server while developing (outside of making changes to method signatures & whatnot)
2. Good tooling support
3. Easy, repeatable setup -- pretty much "checkout and run"

Thanks!

Comment: Have you try the spring Tool Suite? Its perfect for spring Apps, specially for spring boot.

Comment: Yeah, we love STS and have a few guys using it. I'm pretty attached to IntelliJ now as it's got really great database tools also

Answer (score 1):

You don't need tomcat for class reloading anymore. With Spring-boot 1.2 you can just debug the maven target spring-boot:run and have class reloading.
This works for me in intellij.

Comment: I just tried this and got things working, but I'm not able to set breakpoints / use the IDE for debugging. Did you have to manually configure the debugger?

Comment: No, I just have a regular spring-boot maven project with the spring-boot plugin added to the build section. Then I start the spring-boot:run target in debug mode. Then I can set breakpoints in the code.

Comment: @PatrickCornelissen are you on Windows? Because on Linux there is a issue regarding the pid of the executable gradle/maven task bootRun. It makes a child process through fork and when you stop the task from IDEA it does stop the parent process, not the child. So the port is still blocked by it and you have to kill it manually

Comment: When you run the main class itself intelliJ doesn't use gradle/maven to run it. But even when using maven/gradle I have not experienced any problems with old java processes so far, but i'm working on a Mac. I can't stand windows anymore ;-)